# Does microsoft bot or luis provide an interface for tracking failed interaction and let us map them to the correct intent?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have setup a microsoft bot with LUIS and I am wondering if Microsoft provides an interface for tracking all interaction either failed or detected and allow us to map them to correct intent like Dialogflow and Microsoft Bot Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look on the documentation. The main regarding your question is the new `Dashboard` feature announced at Microsoft Build 2019.

Basically it provides graphs like this one:

[image: Predictions]

Or this one, by intent:

[image: By intent]

Those graphs allow direct access to the intents / utterances which have problems.

See documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-use-dashboard

Note: it was also possible before the arrival of this dashboard feature

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas it is really helpful for me in order to get the answer to my query.